# Java Object Constructors and Good Practices

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, constructor

I am currently working on a Java EE application and so I have multiple layers in my application server-side (succintly) :

- Entities and DAO,
- BO and services
- DTOs and Controller

My question is, since I always convert Entities to BO to prevent DB overwrites and reducing workload, is it good practice to include a constructor in BO that takes an Entity as parameters ?

See my code below :

**Livraison.java**

```
package my.tree.model;

imports


@Entity
public class Livraison {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;
    private LocalDate date;
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "FournisseurId", nullable = false)
    private Fournisseur fournisseur;
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "CategorieId", nullable = false)
    private Categorie categorie;
    private Integer netTotal;
    private String prefixCode;
    private Integer compte;
    @Transient
    private List<Palette> palettes = new ArrayList<>();

    public Livraison() {}

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }
    
    //getters and setters
}
```

**LivraisonBo.java**

```
package my.tree.bo;

import Livraison;

public class LivraisonBo {
    private int id;
    private String date;
    private int fournisseurId;
    private int categorieId;
    private Integer netTotal;
    private String prefix;
    private Integer compte;


    public LivraisonBo() {
    }

    //classic constructor
    public LivraisonBo(int id, String date, int fournisseurId, int categorieId, Integer netTotal, String prefix, Integer compte) {
        this.id = id;
        this.date = date;
        this.fournisseurId = fournisseurId;
        this.categorieId = categorieId;
        this.netTotal = netTotal;
        this.prefix = prefix;
        this.compte = compte;
    }

    // constructor taking an entity as parameter
    public LivraisonBo(Livraison l) {
        this.id = l.getId();
        this.date = l.getDate().toString();
        this.fournisseurId = l.getFournisseur().getId();
        this.categorieId = l.getCategorie().getId();
        this.netTotal = l.getNetTotal();
        this.prefix = l.getPrefixCode();
        this.compte = l.getCompte();
    }
    
    //getters and setters
}
```

Is it good practice ? Or should I put this method in a service class ?
Thank you for your help.

Comment: There is a `StackExchange` side for code reviews, I think you should ask this question there.

Comment: I will look at it, thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion rather create Converter classes that will do the conversion to and from Entities and BO.

If you create BO constructor with Entity as parameter, In that way your BO will have dependency on Entities. Which is not a good practice. Because then the one who will be using BO will need to have to have definition of Entities also available with them.

And the first option with multiple parameter is also not a good practice. Keeping parameter less than 5 is considered good practice.

If you create a different converter class with two parameters Entity and BO, will make code more cleaner and readable. As well as, will reduce unwanted dependencies in code.

Comment: That was the issue that was bothering me, but i didn't know if I should go at it another way. Thank you for your insights !

Comment: Agree, and adding my 2c: There are libraries that make the conversion between similar objects very easy - see e.g. Mapstruct, so knock yourself out with converter classes; they are implemented automatically. Additionally, it is the model (or domain) that should be the logical center of the implementation, not the persistence logic. So, I prefer to name business objects with the domain name (e.g. `Livraison` here) and give a different name to the JPA entities, DTOs etc (e.g. `LivraisonEntity`, `LivraisonDto` etc).

Comment: @NikosParaskevopoulos Yes, keeping names what you have suggested, would be better.